# Packet Forwarding on Debian 11

Tags: debian, networking, bridge

I am running Debian 11 on a small form factor box.

I am wanting to take all traffic from a network tap upstream on ethernet interface `eno2` and output it on sfp+ interface `eno8`.

I've set up bridging using the following commands:

```bsh
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eno2 eno8
ip link set br0 up
```

When I do a `tcpdump -ni eno2` I see a TON of traffic, which is expected. But when I do a `tcpdump -ni eno8` I see very little traffic and it seems to be limited to UDP traffic.  I'm wanting all traffic from `eno2` to go to `eno8`.

Somehow it's not bridging the TCP traffic.

The output of `ip a`

```
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:72:d0:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp7s0
    inet 10.0.20.250/24 brd 10.0.50.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ae1f:6bff:fe72:d02a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:72:d0:2b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp8s0
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:72:d0:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp11s0f0
5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:72:d0:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp11s0f1
6: eno5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:72:d0:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp11s0f2
7: eno6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:72:d0:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp11s0f3
8: eno7: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:72:d9:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0f0
9: eno8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:72:d9:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0f1
16: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 72:69:25:12:99:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::7069:25ff:fe12:99da/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Can anyone point me in a direction to solve this issue?

Comment: @roaima Just added output of ```ip a```

Comment: A bridge is a logical interface made up of multiple physical interfaces. Usually configured for fault redundancy to account for possible hardware failures.
Look into IPTables and don't forget to set the kernel parameter `net.ipv4.ip_forward`

Comment: @Deathgrip the OP's not forwarding, they're bridging

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer:

The kernal code doesn't really implement a bridge, but more of a virtual switch. So it will learn what MAC addresses belong to which port and only forward the traffic to that port.

If you set `brctl setaging br0 0` the box won't retain the MAC information.

It is now working.  Thanks to all who looked at this!

Comment: So you mean you changed the bridge from behaving like a switch to behaving like a hub? Couldn't guess that in the question.